# How to get ClearCase stream name by a given view path?

Tags: linux, unix, clearcase

Let's say I'm inside a view on Linux (snapshot or dynamic). I forgot what's the stream that that view belongs to.

How do I get it? Should I extract if from the config-spec (after `-mkbranch`) or is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `-cview` option of the [`lsstream` command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsstream.htm):

```
cleartool lsstream -cview
```

With [fmt_ccase](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsstream.htm):

```
cleartool lsstream -fmt "%n" -cview
```

I like to see where this stream is located within a project, so I usually do a:

```
cleartool lsstream -cview -anc
```