# files not loading in my snapshot view but load only fist two directories

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am trying to load a component vob in a snapshot view but the files don't get loaded there.
What might be the problem?

First time I did:

```
cleartool update -add_loadrules siri_tire
```

And I see directories inside `siri_tire` got loaded but after that it is blank then I ran the following:

```
C:\Users\tony\tony_testsnapshot1>cleartool update -add_loadrules siri_tire\apptire
cleartool: Warning: Skipped adding a load rule for "\siri_tire\apptire": it is
 covered by the existing load rule for "\siri_tire".
Processing dir "\siri_tire\apptire".
End dir "\siri_tire\apptire".

.
Done loading "\siri_tire\apptire" (1 objects, copied 0 KB).
Log has been written to "C:\Users\tony\tony_testsnapshot1\update.2014-03-1
8T164137-0400.updt".
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a:

```
cd C:\Users\tony\tony_testsnapshot1
cleartool catcs
```

You should see a load rule `load \siri_tire`.

So loading isn't an issue.

What is are the selection rules. You need to check:

- if you have any selection rule applying to `\siri_tire\apptire`.
- if this is UCM, does your stream to which your view is associated, include a baseline of a component with a root folder `\siri_tire\apptire`

To get the stream associated to your view, see "[How to get ClearCase stream name by a given view path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19129658/6309)".

```
cd C:\Users\tony\tony_testsnapshot1
cleartool lsstream -cview -anc
cleartool lsstream -fmt "%n" -cview
```