# How to list branches associated with a view in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I have checked in some files in a branch but unfortunately I forgot the branch name but I remember my view name to which my branch is associated. I also checked my config spec but the branch which is written in the config spec is not the branch that I want.

Actually I created two branches in a view but one branch name I forgot and as I said in config spec also only one branch name is written. Is there any way where I can list all branches associated with a particular view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: only an UCM view has an associated branch (through its stream).
See "[How to obtain UCM stream and baseline with `cleartool`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4440593/6309)" or "[How to get ClearCase stream name by a given view path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19129658/6309)"

```
cleartool lsstream -fmt "%n" -cview
```

A non-UCM view would have any selection rules you want in its config spec.
You need to do a [`cleartool lsvtree /path/to/a/file`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsvtree.htm) (add `--graph` for the graphical view) in order to see its versions and the branches involved.

Comment: Thanks Von you again helped me.